# Debugging Qualcomm FFA running Android (kernel) using Trace 32

Tags: android, debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, trace32

I would like to know the procedure the set up Android Kernel debugging using Trace 32 for a phone based on a `Qualcomm chipset.`

There are quiet a few `cmm scripts` available in the Android code I synced from `Code Aurora Forum`. But I don't know which ones are needed for Kernel debugging. The code was synced from `msm7630 ICS branch`.

```
I would like to specifically debug the display driver that is using MDDI (Mobile Device Digital Interface).
```

Being new to Trace 32 debugging I'd also like some help on that too.
Any pointers/help is much appreciated.

Thanks!